# how to fill a array of class? i need this to solve a arrayoutofboundsexception

Tags: java, arrays

i want to fill array restaurante with random values. how do i do that? because when empty give me nullpointerexception exception. i already tried to do Arrays.fill put it doenst work. Or a solution for the exception

```
private Restaurante[] restaurante= new Restaurante[100];

for (int i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {

    String[] row = lines[i].toString().split("-");
    identificador[i] = Integer.parseInt(row[0]);
    restaurante[i].setNome(row[1]);
    restaurante[i].setLugares(Integer.parseInt(row[2]));
    restaurante[i].setLocalidade(row[3]);
    restaurante[i].setTipoDeComida(row[4]);
    if (identificador[i] == this.id) {            
        linhasescritas[contador]=i;
        contador++;

        model.addRow(row);
    }
}
```

the exception is in line restaurante[i].setNome(row[1]);

Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: You do not get the ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException because the array is empty, you get it because you access an index, which is out of bounds (i.e. negative or >= the array's length). You get the `IndexOutOfBoundsException` most probably because the array `lines` is longer than the array `Restaurante`. The exception most probably reads like this: `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBounds: 100`

Comment: As @Turing85 said. Might also be helpful if you posted the actual exception so anyone trying to help you could see which line it's happening on. Either `i` becomes >= 100, or one of the lines doesn't have the right number of "-".

Comment: i was wrog the exception was of nullpointer. Sorry

Comment: rhe error was in the line restaurante[i].setNome(row[1]);

Comment: Please edit your question and add this information, as well as the whole stacktrace of the exception.

Answer (score 0):

Your error is that you did initialize the whole array

```
private Restaurante[] restaurante= new Restaurante[100];
```

but not each of its elements with

```
restaurante[i] = new Restaurante();
```

Hence you get the NullPointer error on

```
restaurante[i].setNome(row[1]);
```

because `restaurante[i]` is still `null`. So insert

```
restaurante[i] = new Restaurante();
```

before this line and the error should vanish.

---

Another problem may be that the reference to `row[1]` is only valid if `lines[i].toString().split("-");` returns at least two elements. You should additionally take care of that with an `if` clause or something similar.